# Show tooltip for dynamic content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following HTML code that shows a dynamic number of rows with information, and then there is an image link that I click to get some **specific information about the clicked row** based on the `compentence_ID`field..

```
            echo "<td>".$compi['Competence_ID']."</td>";
            echo "<td><p style='text-align: center;'>".$compi['Competence_Group']."</p></td>";
            if(isset($compi['Competence_class'])){echo "<td>".$compi['Competence_class']."</td>";}else echo "<td><p style='text-align: center;'>-</p></td>";
            echo "<td>".$compi['Competence_Description']."</td>";
            echo "<td class='evaluation'>";
                echo "<select class='ownlevelselect' id='ownlevelselect-.".$compi['Competence_ID']."' name='level-".$compi['Competence_ID']."' >";
                   if (isset($compi['ownlevel']) && $compi['ownlevel']!= '' && !empty($compi['ownlevel']) && $compi['ownlevel']!= 0) {
                      echo "<option selected value='".$compi['ownlevel']."' selected='selected'>".$compi['ownlevel']."</option>";

                    }
                    echo "<option value='' >--</option>";
                    echo "<option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option>";
                echo "</select>";
                echo $compi['ownlevel'];

// Below are the links I click to view the content
                echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.INDEX.'?categ='.$_GET['categ'].'&action='.$_GET['action'].'&subaction=viewlevels'.'&levels='.$compi['Competence_ID'].'">';
                echo '<img class="linkki" src="'.KUVAT.'paivita.gif" alt="'._("tiedot").'" title="'._("What is this?").'"/></a>';
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
```

This works, and I can see the corresponding info based on the ID posted. But I am wondering if there is anyway to show that information in a tooltip without having to click the link and POST the ID. 
Here is the script to retrieve the Data from DB that I show when the image is clicked.

```
    function fetchlevels($Competence_id){
    $this->query="SELECT * FROM levels WHERE comp_id=".$_REQUEST['levels'];
    $tulos=$this->suoritaKysely();
    return $tulos;
}
```

Comment: can you share the script which loads this content

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is: you can do it with ajax.

We can provide the exact code here but you maybe would like to understand the concept so i believe this next video tutorial is a great place to start.

[youtube video tutorial: Loading Dynamic Content on MouseOver](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlJBKEhCXqY)

In the description of the video you can find a download link to the video tutorials and files associated with them. What you need is example number 2.

For the example to work you just need to change the config file: connect.php and this database

--

### -- Database: `ajax`

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `data`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `data`

INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `title`, `fname`, `lname`) VALUES
(1, 'Web Developer', 'Chris', 'Johnson'),
(2, 'Web Designer', 'Joe', 'Black'),
(3, 'Teacher', 'Jason', 'McIntosh'),
(4, 'family man', 'Jake', 'Kawaguchi'),
(5, 'Sans Man Card', 'Brett', 'Williams'),
(6, 'I don''t know...', 'Topher', 'Howden'),
(7, 'Gamer', 'Jason', 'Luzader'),
(8, 'Wingman', 'Chuck', 'Strong'),
(9, 'Basketball Player', 'Chuck', 'Barkley'),
(10, 'Singer', 'Marta', 'Zore');

Answer (score 0):

In Code

```
echo '<a target="_blank" compId='$compi['Competence_ID']' href="#">';
echo '<img class="linkki" src="'.KUVAT.'paivita.gif" alt="'._("tiedot").'" title="'._("What is this?").'"/></a>';
```

Pardon me if something wrong in above PHP code. basic idea is set the id on attribute of anchor tag

```
 <script>
  $( document ).tooltip({
  items: "img",
  content: function() {
    var element = $( this );
    var parent=element .parent();
    if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
      var text =  $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: remote_url, async: false, }).responseText;//remoe_url is url of your PHP whenre you have code to return the content in tooltip. You can take id as parent.attr('compId')
      return text;
    }
  }
 });
  </script>
```

Comment: I cant see where you are getting the ID of the element in your example?

Comment: Edited to show how can you get ID that you are passing in href ... while making the ajax call in tooltip. read the comments in the code.

Comment: Im really sorry I am a very newbie. Do I have to remove then the onclick attribute from the image. if Yes, shouldn't there be a `click` element in your code?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ go though this and its examples. you can aslo see code snippets there. Normally you show tooltip on mouseOver...not on click...